# Pass multiple values selectedincheckboxto anotherpage to Delete

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to store the multiple values selected in checkbox from one page to another in which another page will perform the delete operation.I want to pass the value and receive the value in another page.Here is my code:

```
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
<?php include 'menu_admin.php';?>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Form.css">
<?php include 'connect.php';?>

<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ads";
$result = $db->query($sql);

//the function num_rows() checks if there are more than zero rows returned
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   echo "<table><tr><th>SELECT</th><th>ADID</th><th>ADName</th><th>ADCATEGORY</th><th>CONTACTNUMBER</th><th>EXPIRATIONDATE</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> 
        <input type='checkbox' id = 'checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=".$row['ADID']." > ".$row['ADID']."
    </td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["ADID"]. "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=#>" .$row["ADNAME"]. "</a></td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["ADCATEGORY"]. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["CONTACTNUMBER"]. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["EXPIRATIONDATE"]. "</td>";



echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}




        $result->free();
?>

<?php 


 $myCheckVar = $_POST['checkbox'];
?>



      <input type="submit" value='Delete' name="Delete" onClick="window.location='deletead.php?myvalue=$myCheckVar';"/>


    <input type="submit" value='Update' name="update"/>
    <input type="submit" value="New" name="new" onClick="window.location='post_ad.php?user=$username';"/>
```

Please Help

Comment: you want to delete data according to check box ADID pass ????

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your table in a form tag and set the action to your control file. You can access the POST variable as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the code below. Todo: change YOUR_URL_TO_CATCH_THE_FORM to the URL which needs to catch the form.

```
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
<?php include 'menu_admin.php';?>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Form.css">
<?php include 'connect.php';?>

<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ads";
$result = $db->query($sql);

//the function num_rows() checks if there are more than zero rows returned
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   echo "<form action=\"YOUR_URL_TO_CATCH_THE_FORM\" method=\"POST\">";
   echo "<table><tr><th>SELECT</th><th>ADID</th><th>ADName</th><th>ADCATEGORY</th><th>CONTACTNUMBER</th><th>EXPIRATIONDATE</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> 
        <input type='checkbox' id = 'checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=".$row['ADID']." > ".$row['ADID']."
    </td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["ADID"]. "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=#>" .$row["ADNAME"]. "</a></td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["ADCATEGORY"]. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["CONTACTNUMBER"]. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["EXPIRATIONDATE"]. "</td>";



echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Then catch the form POST in your "YOUR_URL_TO_CATCH_THE_FORM" php with something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']) &&  !empty($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value)
        {
            echo 'This is checkbox value '.$key.': '.$value;
        }
    }
}
```